# FullCalendar - how to prevent an Event that occurs in the past from being dragged

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I want to prevent an Event that occurs in the past from being dragged. I have tried using;

```
eventConstraint: {
    start: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'),/* This constrains it to today or later */
    end: '2100-01-01' // hard coded goodness unfortunately
},
```

I can prevent dragging **to** past dates with:

```
eventDrop: function(info) {
    var eventObj = info.event;
    var check = moment(eventObj.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    var today = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    if(check < today) {
        revertFunc(); //Put the Event back where it came from
    } else {
        //code
    }
},
```

Full code:

```
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        firstDay: 0, //Sunday
        weekends: true, //Show the weekends
        businessHours: { // days of week. an array of zero-based day of week integers (0=Sunday)
            daysOfWeek: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ], // Monday - Friday
            startTime: '09:00', // a start time
            endTime: '17:00', // an end time
        },
        initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
        headerToolbar: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listMonth'
        },
        locale: 'en-gb',
        selectable: true, // gives ability to select multiple days and then have a callback event when this occurs
        buttonIcons: false, // show the prev/next text
        weekNumbers: true, // show week numbers
        navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
        editable: true, // can make changes and add changes
        dayMaxEvents: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        displayEventEnd: true, // display the end time
        eventTimeFormat: {
            hour: '2-digit',
            minute: '2-digit',
          },// display time with minutes
        eventDisplay: 'block', //Changes an event with start and end times from a list-item to a block
        eventConstraint: {
            start: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'),/* This constrains it to today or later */
            end: '2100-01-01', // hard coded goodness unfortunately
        },
        
        events: responseJson1a,//Populate Event using JSON
```

Answer (score 0):

set key editable to false when you define your past events on fullCalendar

```js
events: [
      {
        title: 'Business Lunch',
        start: '2021-11-03T13:00:00',
        constraint: 'businessHours',
        editable:false,
      },
      ...
      ...
]
```

Comment: Hi Hery, thank you; however, not quite what I want. I want the constraint for all Events, so using eventConstraint not constraint. I have update my question with the full code.

Comment: I think I can use "oldEvent" to get the original start date; however, I can not find an example of how to use it.